# How to replace a value in first column onwards with a new value based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble like this:

```r
input_data <- tibble::tribble(

 # Number of samples can be more than 2.
 # Number of genes around 24K

 ~Genes,     ~Sample1, ~Sample2,
 "Ncr1",       8.2,      10.10,
 "Il1f9",      3.2,      20.30,
 "Stfa2l1",    2.3,      0.3,
 "Klra10",     5.5,      12.0,
 "Dcn",        1.8,      0,
 "Cxcr2",      1.3,      1.1,
 "Foo",        20,       70
)

input_data
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>     Genes Sample1 Sample2
#>     <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    Ncr1     8.2    10.1
#> 2   Il1f9     3.2    20.3
#> 3 Stfa2l1     2.3     0.3
#> 4  Klra10     5.5    12.0
#> 5     Dcn     1.8     0.0
#> 6   Cxcr2     1.3     1.1
#> 7     Foo    20.0    70.0
```

What I want to do is to replace values from *2nd column* (Sample1) onwards.
Please not that sample name can be anything, so preferably use column index.

If the value is less than `k=2.0` replace it with 0.
Finally we hope to get this result:

```r
  Genes Sample1 Sample2
  Ncr1     8.2    10.1
  Il1f9    3.2    20.3
  Stfa2l1  2.3     0
  Klra10   5.5    12.0
  Dcn       0      0.0
  Cxcr2     0       0
  Foo    20.0    70.0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: simply: `input_data[input_data < 2] <- 0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
input_data %>% 
       mutate_at(vars(matches("Sample")), funs(replace(., .<2, 0)))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
#    Genes Sample1 Sample2
#    <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    Ncr1     8.2    10.1
#2   Il1f9     3.2    20.3
#3 Stfa2l1     2.3     0.0
#4  Klra10     5.5    12.0
#5     Dcn     0.0     0.0
#6   Cxcr2     0.0     0.0
#7     Foo    20.0    70.0
```

Or if we want column index

```
input_data %>% 
      mutate_at(2:3, funs(replace(., .<2, 0)))
```

Comment: Can we use column index instead? Cos, sample name can be anything.